# How to draw low-size/weight images of geometric shapes

Tags: website-design, png, jpg

I searched this on google but didn't find anything useful.

I want to draw images for my website for mathematical questions like circles, triangles, angles, etc.I tried `Dia` for this purpose but the best result I am getting is :

2-3KB (svg)

12-13KB(png)

12-15KB(jpg)

But I want the maximum size of 1.5KB for the image. Maybe this can be done followed by using a compression tool. But isn't there any direct way/tool which graphic designers use?

PS: I don't want to use bulldozer (Photoshop) for a small task

Comment: Sorry, are you asking how to generate these?

Comment: Here's an image of a triangle that is 201 bytes: http://i.stack.imgur.com/u0LTM.png. I'm guessing that doesn't answer your question, though. This is impossible to answer without knowing what resolution the images need to be. Provide examples of the kinds of images you need to produce.

Answer (score 1):

In Photoshop you can use "Save for Web" and either to PNG24 or PNG8 and based on the size of the image it shouldn't be more than 1-2KB

or a faster variant: http://www.imageoptimizer.net/